# Prompt grep only display match results

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Hi I'm currently using grep function to do a search on my /etc/passwd file to check if GID enterred matched the system GID. But I'm trying to do a grep function but only showing echo content instead of displaying all the matched GID. Here's my output below:

```
    elif grep -n $gid /etc/passwd|cut -f4 -d":"
      then 
    echo "$gid exist!"
    exit1
```

Comment: aside: the existence (or not) of a gid in /etc/passwd does not tell you whether a GID exists or is in use ... checking /etc/group is going to be more reliable on systems that aren't networked ... on networked systems, things get much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The `-q` option suppresses output:

```
elif grep -q $gid /etc/passwd
  then 
echo "$gid exist!"
exit1
```

`cut` is not needed. **Note:** this will match the number `$gid` anywhere in the `passwd`, you can further parse the data to specifically limit your search to the `gid` field. Example:

```
elif awk -F ':' '{ print $4; }' /etc/passwd | grep -q $gid
then 
echo "$gid exist!"
exit1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your command by using option "-o" that print only the matched parts of a matching line.
You must also use a regular expression to make sure to have the right GID and not a partial one or a UID.

The grep command should be something like:

```
grep -o -E "^[^:]+:[^:]*:[0-9]+:$gid:" /etc/passwd
```

The whole solution would be:

```
if [ condition ] ; then
    command
elif [ -n `grep -o -E "^[^:]+:[^:]*:[0-9]+:$gid:" /etc/passwd` ] ; then
    echo "$gid exists!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: thanks! but i don't need it to me so sophisticated still a year 1 students!:)